# Finding specific primitives within a binary file

Tags: c++, file, binary, primitive-types

Is there any ways to find a specific primitive within a binary file(such as fread in MATLAB or BinaryReadLists in Mathematica)?  Specifically,  I want to scan my file until it reaches, say a int8_t precision number, then store it in a variable, then scan for another primitive(unsigned char, double, etc..)?

I am rewriting code from MATLAB that does this, so the format of the file is known.

I want to read n bytes of only the specified type (32-bit int, char, ..) in a file. Ex: Read only the first 12 bytes of my file if they return to be 8-bit integers

Comment: Nope.  If you have a binary file but don't know the format of the content, then it's impossible to tell what the types of anything are.  a `int` and a `float` and a `char*` are indistinguishable.

Comment: Thanks.  I should of mentioned, but I do know the format.  I am rewriting code from MATLAB that does this.

Comment: If you know the format then..... I totally don't understand your question.  If you know the format, why are you "scanning until you find a int8_t"?  Just tell us what you want to do, and odds are, it's easy.

Comment: I want to read n bytes of only the specified type (32-bit int, char, ..) in a file.  Ex:  Read only the first 12 bytes of my file if they return to be 8-bit integers

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes no sense to me, but here's a bunch of random information on how to read a binary file:

```
struct myobject { //so you have your data
    char weight;
    double value;
};
//for primitives in a binary format you simply read it in
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, myobject& data) {
    return in >> data.weight >> data.value; 
    //we don't really care about failures here
}
//if you don't know the length, that's harder
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, std::vector<myobject>& data) {
    int size;
    in >> size; //read the length
    data.clear();
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) { //then read that many myobject instances
        myobject obj;
        if (in >> obj)
            data.push_back(obj);
        else //if the stream fails, stop
            break;            
    }
    return in;
}
int main() {
    std::ifstream myfile("input.txt", std::ios_base::binary); //open a file
    std::vector<myobject> array;
    if (myfile >> array) //read the data!
        //well that was easy
    else
        std::cerr << "error reading from file";
    return 0;
};
```

Also, you can use the `.seek(position)` member of `ifstream` to skip directly to a specific point in the file, if you happen to know where to find the data you're looking for.

Oh, you just want to read the first 12 bytes of the file as 8 bit integers, and then the next 12 bytes as int32_t?

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream myfile("input.txt", std::ios_base::binary); //open a file

    std::vector<int8_t> data1(12); //array of 12 int8_t
    for(int i=0; i<12; ++i) //for each int
        myfile >> data1[i]; //read it in
    if (!myfile) return 1; //make sure the read succeeded

    std::vector<int32_t> data2(3); //array of 3 int32_t
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) //for each int
        myfile >> data2[i]; //read it in
    if (!myfile) return 1; //make sure the read succeeded

    //processing
}
```

Comment: Right, I can do that.  But what if I want to read the next 3 bytes as 32-bit integers after I've read the first 12 as 8-bit.  Is there anyway to do it, so it's not...messy?

Comment: @user2221493: I assume you mean 12 bytes as 32-bit integers (3 integers total).  It's quite easy, you just read more.  I've shown an example in my question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution to your problem is in understanding the difference between these two doc pages:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Both versions of fread let you pull in an array of items from a binary file. I'm assuming from your question that you know the size and shape of the array you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  const size_t NumElements = 128; // hopefully you know
  int8_t myElements[NumElements];
  FILE *fp = fopen("mydata.bin", "rb");
  assert(fp != NULL);
  size_t countRead = fread(myElements, sizeof(int8_t), NumElements, fp);
  assert(countRead = NumElements);

  // do something with myElements
}
```